# css ul bullet points too close together - not lining up

Tags: css

I have 3 items in a <`ul>` unordered list and after i put in the `<a href>` hyperlinks the bullet points are too close together.  The second bullet point matches the second line of the first bullet point.

How do I get the bullet point match to up the start of `<li>` item?

Comment: Can you post some code please? Or even a jsfiddle ?

Comment: put it in a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=txm9CU2toT it looks ok on the fiddle but its not ok on my website... there might be other css code overruling it.  is there an inline solution ?

Comment: I've tried replicating what you've described in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1sgvpbym/), please edit it to include your code so we can see what's going wrong

Comment: that is the code - i just changed the urls and text... on my website the same code doesnt display the second bullet point in line with the start of the second line - it put its on the second line of the first point.

Comment: must be some other css on your page breaking it

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yes..how can i overrule it ? i dont want to remove css..

Comment: thanks oriol but i have been looking at this problem for a while , i just didn't see a solution

Comment: I notice your markup starts with a `<p>` tag before the `<ul>` try removing that

Comment: removed the <p> - no change

Comment: can you add the rest of your css to the fiddle?

Comment: sorry its taking the css from the css file, if i delete that it removes the problem -

Comment: how do i overrule the .css file ? it makes the ul elements smaller - i have font set to 18px on the webpage but it still makes the ul elments small

Comment: put your new css styling below the original rules, CSS stands for cascading stylesheets so the further down styles take precedence but why not just change the original styling?

Comment: i would need to copy the css in the css main file and put it in the file the webpage i am working on  - and give different values (like bigger font).  I guess I could put it in inline but i havent got anything to work yet except deleting the ul li a { } in the css file

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vwa4sbx/)

Setting the styling on the `li`'s rather than their `a`'s fixed the issue

Comment: thanks, its still picking up the css in the other file... i tried replacing the other css but no luck... once I delete it - it solves my problem.

Comment: cool well without seeing the rest of your CSS then I'd say go with getting rid of it if you don't need it, travel light :)